# PHP DateTime credit card expiration

Tags: php, date, validation, datetime, credit-card

I'm trying to use DateTime to check if a credit card expiry date has expired but I'm a bit lost.

I only want to compare the mm/yy date.

Here is my code so far

```
$expmonth = $_POST['expMonth']; //e.g 08
$expyear = $_POST['expYear']; //e.g 15

$rawExpiry = $expmonth . $expyear;

$expiryDateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('my', $rawExpiry);
$expiryDate = $expiryDateTime->format('m y');

$currentDateTime = new \DateTime();
$currentDate = $currentDateTime->format('m y');

if ($expiryDate < $currentDate) {
    echo 'Expired';
} else {
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

I feel i'm almost there but the if statement is producing incorrect results. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. The format of the datess you are working with is not important as PHP does the comparison internally.

```
$expires = \DateTime::createFromFormat('my', $_POST['expMonth'].$_POST['expYear']);
$now     = new \DateTime();

if ($expires < $now) {
    // expired
}
```

Comment: This even works when the date is the current month !

Comment: Tripped me up a little bit, make sure your expiration date is only 2 digits. If it is 4 digits (ex: 2017 instead of 17), then you need to use: 
`$expires = \DateTime::createFromFormat('mY', $_POST['expMonth'].$_POST['expYear']);`

(capitol Y instead of lowercase)

Comment: This is a good answer, but does not take not take into account the actual expiry DATE of the credit/debit card. 

`DateTime::createFromFormat` will use todays date of the month (e.g. 17) if is not specified. This means that a credit card could appear expired when it still has several days to go.

If a card expires 06/20 (i.e. June 2020) then it actually stops working at 00:00:00 on 1st July 2020.

The modify method fixes this.

Comment: I've posted a full answer below.

Comment: This won't work if the expiry month is single-digit… plus the issue pointed out by @featherbelly.

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert This isn't supposed to work with single digits as the OP is specifically working with double digits months.

Comment: Not working for the current month/year because $expires microseconds are .000000
and $now has a non-zero value.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to generate a DateTime object matching the format of your given date string using the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) constructor.

The format ('my') would match any date string with the string pattern 'mmyy', e.g. '0620'. Or for dates with 4 digit years use the format 'mY' which will match dates with the following string pattern 'mmyyyy', e.g. '062020'. It's also sensible to specify the timezone using the [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) class.

```
$expiryMonth = 06;
$expiryYear = 20;
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$expiryTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('my', $expiryMonth.$expiryYear, $timezone);
```

See the [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) page for more formats.

However - for credit/debit card expiry dates you will **also need to take into account the full expiry DATE and TIME** - not just the month and year.

[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) will by default use todays day of the month (e.g. 17) if it is not specified. This means that a credit card could appear expired when it still has several days to go. If a card expires 06/20 (i.e. June 2020) then it actually stops working at 00:00:00 on 1st July 2020. The [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method fixes this. E.g.

```
$expiryTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('my', $expiryMonth.$expiryYear, $timezone)->modify('+1 month first day of midnight');
```

The string `'+1 month first day of midnight'` does three things.

- '+1 month' - add one month.
- 'first day of' - switch to the first day of the month
- 'midnight' - change the time to 00:00:00

The modify method is really useful for many date manipulations!

So to answer the op, this is what you need — with a slight adjustment to format to cater for single digit months:

```
$expiryMonth = 6;
$expiryYear = 20;
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$expiryTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat(
  'm-y',
   $expiryMonth.'-'.$expiryYear,
   $timezone
)->modify('+1 month first day of midnight');

$currentTime = new \DateTime('now', $timezone);

if ($expiryTime < $currentTime) {
    // Card has expired.
}
```

Comment: This won't work if the month is single-digit. A simple fix is to use 'm-y' (or 'm-Y' if the year is four-digit.)

Comment: Months on credit/debit cards are never single digit — numbers under 10 begin with a zero, e.g. 06.

Comment: Never say "never". They're two-digit as written on credit cards, yes; but you can't be sure what the data will be. For example, the Stripe API returns `int(4)` for an expiry month in April – effectively single-digit.

Answer (score 6):

An addition to the above answers.
Be aware that by default the days will also be in the calculation.
For example today is `2019-10-31` and if you run this:

```
\DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', '202111');
```

It will output `2021-12-01`, because day 31 does not exist in November and it will add 1 extra day to your DateTime object with a side effect that you will be in the month December instead of the expected November.

My suggestion is always use the day in your code.

Answer (score 2):

For op's question:

```
$y=15;
$m=05;

if(strtotime( substr(date('Y'), 0, 2)."{$y}-{$m}" ) < strtotime( date("Y-m")  ))
{
  echo 'card is expired';
}
```

For others with full year:

```
$y=2015;
$m=5;

if(strtotime("{$y}-{$m}") < strtotime( date("Y-m")  ))
{
  echo 'card is expired';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be simpler to just compare the string "201709" to the current year-month? Creating datetime objects will cost php some effort, I suppose.

```
if($_POST['expYear']. str_pad($_POST['expMonth'],2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT ) < date('Ym')) {
   echo 'expired';

}
```

edited as Adam states

Comment: You have to use STR_PAD_LEFT as the 4th arg of `str_pad` or you'll get `10` instead of `01`

Answer (score 0):

The [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19496705/4265352) is provided by John Conde above. It it does the minimum amount of processing: creates two correct `DateTime` objects, compares them and that's all it needs.

It could work also as you started but you must format the dates in a way that puts the year first.

Think a bit about it: as dates, `08/15` (August 2015) is after `12/14` (December 2014) but as strings, `'08 15'` is before `'12 14'`.

When the year is in front, even as strings the years are compared first and then, only when the years are equal the months are compared:

```
$expiryDate  = $expiryDateTime->format('y m');
$currentDate = $currentDateTime->format('y m');

if ($expiryDate < $currentDate) {
    echo 'Expired';
} else {
    echo 'Valid';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, as the answer above me says except you need to string pad to the left:

```
isCardExpired($month, $year)
{
    $expires = $year.str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $now = date('Ym');

    return $expires < $now;
}
```

No need to add extra PHP load using `DateTime`

Comment: When working with dates it's always best to use DateTime as it designed specifically for this purpose. The overhead is negligible.

Comment: Having worked a lot with dates I agree, but I find this is more of an integer comparison and I like its simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which is a very popular Datetime extension library. Then this should be:

```php
$expMonth = $_POST['month'];
$expYear = $_POST['year'];
$format_m_y = str_pad($expMonth,2,'0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'.substr($expYear, 2);

$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m-y', $format_m_y)
         ->endOfMonth()
         ->startOfDay();

if ($date->isPast()) {
  // this card is expired
}
```

Also take into consideration the exact date and time expiration:

> Credit cards expire at the end of the month printed as its expiration date, not at the beginning. Many cards actually technically expire one day after the end of that month. In any case, unless they list a specific day of expiration along with month and year, they should work all the way through the end of their expiration month. Cardholders should not wait until the last moment to secure a replacement card. [Source](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/credit-card-expiration-dates-what-you-need-to-know)